# In the usecase [3,5,0,3,4], I receive an error.How did this array fall within the 132 pattern?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

Given an array of n integers nums, a 132 pattern is a subsequence of three integers nums[i], nums[j] and nums[k] such that i < j < k and nums[i] < nums[k] < nums[j].

Return true if there is a 132 pattern in nums, otherwise, return false.
`

```
class Solution 
{
    public boolean find132pattern(int[] nums) 
    {
        int l = 0;
        int r = 2;
        while (r < nums.length)
        {
            int mid=(l+r)/2;
            if (nums[l] < nums[r])
            {
            if (nums[mid]>nums[r]) 
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            l++;
            r++;

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This is my solution. if there is a logical error, could you possibly assist me in solving this?

Comment: If I read the problem statement (https://leetcode.com/problems/132-pattern/description/) correctly then the 132 pattern is 3-5-4 with i=0, j=1, k=4 and nums[i]=3, nums[k]=4, nums[j]=5

Comment: The problem with your solution is that your `mid` value can be any value positioned between the first and third selected from your array, and you are only looking at the one midpoint between the two and ignoring all other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your program is that only the very start has to be `true`. `return [value]` will end the method, meaning if the start or one part is true, but the rest is `false`, your program will still return `true` because it found one part in a "132" format. Rather than returning `true` in your `while` loop, you could try returning `false`:

```
while (r < nums.length) {
    int mid=(l+r)/2;
    if (nums[l] >= nums[r] && nums[mid] <= nums[r]) {
       return false;
    }           
    l++;
    r++;
}
return true;
```

This ensures that if any part of the array's condition is false that it will not give a "false positive".

Alternatively you could add a counter like so:

```
int count = l;
while (r < nums.length) {
    int mid=(l+r)/2;
    if (nums[l] < nums[r] && nums[mid] > nums[r]) {
       count++;       
    }           
    l++;
    r++;
}
if (count == l) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

This makes sure the condition was always `true`.
An even more streamlined version of both these methods, however, would likely just be to do this:

```
int mid=(l+r)/2;
while (r < nums.length && (nums[l] < nums[r] && nums[mid] > nums[r])) {           
    l++;
    r++;
    mid = (l+r)/2;
}
if (r == nums.length) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

This immediately checks if the condition is `true` without the need for an `if` statement or really anything else.

Results of each:

```
Are [3, 5, 0, 3, 4] and [6, 8, 7] in a 132 format?
Solution 1: 
    [3, 5, 0, 3, 4]: no :(
    [6, 8, 7]: yes!
Solution 2: 
    [3, 5, 0, 3, 4]: no :(
    [6, 8, 7]: yes!
Solution 3: 
    [3, 5, 0, 3, 4]: no :(
    [6, 8, 7]: yes!
```

I hope this helped!